# Wrong 1st argument Type Uri/FileProvider Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get `cameraFragment.this` to work in a Fragment but it keeps telling me "Wrong 1st argument type etc"

```
public void dispatchPicTaken(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != 
null){
            File imgFile = null;
            imgFile = createPhotoFile();

            if(imgFile != null) {
                pathToFile = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoURI = 
FileProvider.getUriForFile(cameraFragment.this, "test", imgFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `getActivity()` to get the context in a `fragment` instead of `cameraFragment.this`

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "test", imgFile);
```